# Invalid Syntax error in Python Code I copied from the Internet

Tags: python, syntax

One of my early courses in the University I attend, was some basic training in Python 3 years ago. Now I was looking for a program that could help me resize some Grid stuff and I found something that could help me in Python. I reinstalled Python to my PC and found my old editor. However when I run the code I get an invalid syntax error that I can't understand. This is the part of the code that the error appears in :

```
def downsize(mode, cell_size, inpath, outpath):

  from VolumeData import fileformats
  try:
    grid_data = fileformats.open_file(inpath)
  except fileformats.Uknown_File_Type, e:
    sys.stderr.write(str(e))
    sys.exit(1)

  reduced = Reduced_Grid(grid_data, mode, cell_size)

  from VolumeData.netcdf.netcdf_grid import write_grid_as_netcdf
  write_grid_as_netcdf(reduced, outpath)
```

The exact invalid syntax error is in the "except fileformats.Uknown_File_Type, e:" line. Can you help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Python 3.x, you cannot use `except fileformats.Uknown_File_Type, e`. The comma works as an `as` statement (in the `try`/`except` block), so you should replace it with: `except fileformats.Uknown_File_Type as e`.

The comma works in Python 2.7, but not 3.x. However, the `as` should work for both.

Reference: [Handling errors in Python 3.3](http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you misspelled 'Unknown'?

Comment: No it's not that. Unfortunately I copy pasted the version I wrote my self from scratch in case there was some format problem (in which i mispelled Uknown). The editor shows that the error is on the comma between "type" and "e:"