# From Python Code to a Working Executable File (Downsizing Grid Files Program)

Tags: python, syntax

I posted a question earlier about a syntax error here [Invalid Syntax error in Python Code I copied from the Internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15177040/invalid-syntax-error-in-python-code-i-copied-from-the-internet). Fortunately, my problem was fixed really fast thanks to you. However now that there is no syntax error I found myself helpless as I don't know what to do now with this code. As I've said I've done some basic Python Training 3 years ago but the human brain seems to forget things so fast.

So in a few words, I need to reduce the grid resolution of some files to half and I've been searching for a way to do it for weeks. Luckily I found some python code that seems to do exactly what I am looking for. The code is this :

```
#!/bin/env python
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Reduce grid data to a smaller size by averaging over cells of specified
# size and write the output as a netcdf file.  xyz_origin and xyz_step
# attributes are adjusted.
#
# Syntax: downsize.py <x-cell-size> <y-cell-size> <z-cell-size>
#                       <in-file> <netcdf-out-file>
#
import sys

import Numeric

from VolumeData import Grid_Data, Grid_Component

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
def downsize(mode, cell_size, inpath, outpath):

  from VolumeData import fileformats
  try:
    grid_data = fileformats.open_file(inpath)
  except fileformats.Uknown_File_Type as e:
    sys.stderr.write(str(e))
    sys.exit(1)

  reduced = Reduced_Grid(grid_data, mode, cell_size)

  from VolumeData.netcdf.netcdf_grid import write_grid_as_netcdf
  write_grid_as_netcdf(reduced, outpath)

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Average over cells to produce reduced size grid object.
#
# If the grid data sizes are not multiples of the cell size then the
# final data values along the dimension are not included in the reduced
# data (ie ragged blocks are not averaged).
#
class Reduced_Grid(Grid_Data):

  def __init__(self, grid_data, mode, cell_size):

    size = map(lambda s, cs: s / cs, grid_data.size, cell_size)
    xyz_origin = grid_data.xyz_origin
    xyz_step = map(lambda step, cs: step*cs, grid_data.xyz_step, cell_size)
    component_name = grid_data.component_name
    components = []
    for component in grid_data.components:
      components.append(Reduced_Component(component, mode, cell_size))

    Grid_Data.__init__(self, '', '', size, xyz_origin, xyz_step,
                       component_name, components)

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Average over cells to produce reduced size grid object.
#
class Reduced_Component(Grid_Component):

  def __init__(self, component, mode, cell_size):

    self.component = component
    self.mode = mode
    self.cell_size = cell_size
    Grid_Component.__init__(self, component.name, component.rgba)

  # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  #
  def submatrix(self, ijk_origin, ijk_size):

    ijk_full_origin = map(lambda i, cs: i * cs, ijk_origin, self.cell_size)
    ijk_full_size = map(lambda s, cs: s*cs, ijk_size, self.cell_size)
    values = self.component.submatrix(ijk_full_origin, ijk_full_size)

    if mode == 'ave':
      m = average_down(values, self.cell_size)
```

I have this saved as a .py file and when I double click it, the command prompt appears for a milisecond and then disappears. I managed to take a screenshot of that command prompt which it says "Unable to create process using 'bin/env python "C:\Users...........py".

What I want to do is to be able to do this downsizing using the Syntax that the code tells me to use :

```
# Syntax: downsize.py <x-cell-size> <y-cell-size> <z-cell-size>
    #                       <in-file> <netcdf-out-file>
```

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't run the file by double-clicking it. Run the file by opening a new shell, and typing in the path to the `.py` file (or just `cd` to the parent directory) followed by the arguments you want to pass. For example:

```
python downsize.py 1 2 3 foo bar
```

Comment: Thnx for answering. Let's say the .py file is "C:\downgrid.py", x _cell_size = 2250, y_cell_size = 869, z_cell_size = 0, in-file is "C:\old.grid" and netcdf-out-file is "C:\new.netcdf", can you pls write me the exact correct code to put in the Shell ? Sry but as it seems I am a complete noob :(